# java.net.ConnectException : DocumentBuilder.parse(inputstream) from HttpPost

Tags: java

I am using httppost to connect to a URL which will return xml data.

```
StringEntity myEntity = new StringEntity(inputXMLString,"text/xml","UTF-8");
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(requestURL);
httppost.setEntity(myEntity);
//Set Parameter
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 1200000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 1200000);
//retrieve response
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(IP_ADDRESS);
httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.LOCAL_ADDRESS,addr);
long diff;
long start;
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream inputstream = entity.getContent();
diff = (start - System.currentTimeMillis());
//Then printing diff
return inputstream;
```

The inputstreamis used by DocumentBuilder to parse into Documnent object. It works fine in most of the cases but sometimes i get a connect exception as below

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown         
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
   .................
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: It is because of your network. Is this url in your local network or internet?

Comment: its internal only.... I want to prove the network guys that its because of the network overload..

Comment: increase your connection timeout and check.

Comment: I incresad to 5 mins. Still I am getting connection timeout. I calculated the time diff at HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost); I got the response within 1 seconds.. I am using the inputStream directly for DocumentBuilder.parse. I will try to convert stream to String and then parse it.

Comment: So u are getting response within 1 seconds for all ur requests? Is there any request you are not getting response at all?

Comment: Yes i am getting within 1 sec.. And I always get response.. When i tried to convert to String its still giving me the error. But in between i got another exception org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectionException Connection to ... refused.

Comment: can u edit the above code to show how you calculate the response time?

Comment: edited..... BTW thanks Sonic for promt reply and suggestions..

Comment: You can just pass url to Document Builder to fetch and get data .No need to create http connection.this will reduce yor work.

Comment: @Nargis. I need to pass inputXMLString and based on that i am getting some response, so how can we directly use parse(url)??